# How is long-lasting whipped cream made?

Tags: cream, whipped-cream

Cakes made of whipped-cream by professionals last for a long time in a consistent, white state. However, from what I know, whipped cream tends to become yellow and return to a more liquid state in a few hours. I prepare whipped cream with just the cream and an electric mixer, so I assume there's some magic ingredient or process to keep the thing stable. Where's the trick ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two levels to this question. If you are using modern whipping cream as a starting point, then the trick for a longer lasting whipped cream is stabilization. If this is some farm bought milk you are skimming the cream from, then you have the additional problem that your cream is not fatty enough. Modern creams are concentrated with a centrifuge.

To get good whipped cream, whip it cold until it [doubles in volume and you get firm peaks](http://www.bonappetit.com/tipstools/videos/2008/04/whipping_cream). Stabilize the whipped cream by hanging it in a cheese cloth in the refrigerator or by adding gelatin.To use the gelatin, dissolve 2 teaspoons of unflavored gelatin into 2 tablespoons of cold water. Work out the lumps. After the gelatin expands, mix in a quarter cup of cream and heat the mixture to dissolve the gelatin.  Cool over ice and mix a bit. Complete 2 cups of cream and proceed as you would to finish your whipped cream.

Comment: by 'Complete 2 cups of cream' do you mean make up the quarter cup of cream with the gelatin in to 2 cups in total?

Comment: I meant add an extra one and three quarter cups of cream into the bowl with the cream and gelatin mixture. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few things that you can add: agar-agar, cornstarch, powdered sugar (which has cornstarch), gelatin (requires blooming in water first), powdered milk, etc.

Search online and you should find the proper ratios of each one to use so you don't overdo it.

Answer (score 3):

For stable frosting, I whip heavy cream and cream cheese together (start by whipping the cream cheese, add twice as much cream to it, slowly). Lasts *days* in refrigeration. Slight tangy taste though; whether that's good or bad is up to you...

Answer (score 2):

Real cream with a high fat content + a hardening agent. You can buy it in any supermarket. Just mix it with the cream before whipping.

Comment: What is a "hardening agent"? I've never heard of this.

Comment: @Catija it may be a language issue, in Germany there is a product called "cream stiffener" when translated literally. It is simply a bit of modified starch, maybe with some dextrose for better solubility.

Comment: @rumtscho thanks for the explanation... I've never *looked* for a product like this but I've never been aware of it existing. Some additional background in the answer would be a welcome addition to explain it. As per usual, a two-line answer really doesn't have enough information.

Comment: Idk, here it's 'utrjevalec za smetano'. But it's a small bag off powder usually somewhere near things like cake toppings, puddings, food colors, almost premade  muffins, vanilla sugar,....

Answer (score 1):

bloom some geletin (flavorless! do not just grab a packet of jell-o) and add it to the cream.

for 1 cup of cream 1/2tsp of geletin in 1Tbls of water.